# How to check if divided number is integer and how to take out of symbols row in Delphi?

Tags: delphi

I want to take out of symbols row all integer, which divide with 3.
Can someone please help me how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that the remainder when divided by 3 is zero:

```
IsMultipleOfThree := (num mod 3) = 0;
```

I'm not sure what you mean by "take out of symbols row".